# How do I execute a clean reinstall or factory reset of elementary OS?

Tags: release-hera, system-installation

I dual-booted my Windows laptop to elementary OS a while ago and made a mess of things with settings and software. I want to start over with a clean install. I do not have any files or data I need to save. I just want to restart elementary OS as if I were launching it for the first time. Is there a simple way to do this?

I currently have elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera.

Comment: Just do a reinstall. During the installation process, choose the 'erase disk' option. I can make you a pretty screenshot but it's rather easy and you probably don't need one. Just go ahead and install it like you did the first time, but this time choose to erase the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Like say [@KGII](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/23800/kgiii) your have the option ERASE DISK when you have in the installation guide

after little search with google

[image]